# Why is $-1=e^{\pi i }=e^{2\pi i\frac{1}{2}}\neq (e^{2\pi i})^{\frac{1}{2}}=1^{\frac{1}{2}}=1$ true?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

I thought there was this rule that $e^{xB}=(e^x)^B$?

Also what I don't understand is that $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is defined as the square root of $x$. And because the square root may also be in $\mathbb{C}$ it doesn't matter which number $x$ is because every complex number has a n-th root.

But for $1^{\frac{1}{2}}$ we have the roots $-1$ and $1$, so I could also write $-1$ on the right side then the Statement above would be true and not true at the same time.

But we said the Expression in the Question is correct and to write $-1$ is false. Can somebody explain the reason we choose one Version over another altough they are equivalent?

Comment: To be precise every complex number $($beside $0$$)$ has exactly $n$ distinct $n$th roots.

Comment: @mrtraurho Well, $0$ doesn't have *distinct* $n$th roots.

Comment: @J.G. Thats right. I have not considered this exception.

Comment: Field multiplication is defined on $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$

Comment: Conclusion: using the notation $z^{1/2}$ to mean a single number and simultaneously to mean a set of two numbers, can lead to chaos. Should we be surprised?

Comment: The main problem of taking a root in general is that it happens to be that the root function is a multivalued one. Thus, even within the reals you can state that $5=\sqrt{25}=-5$ which is a contradiction as well.

Comment: @Did Okay so the rule that I have cited above is not valid for complex numbers. But how do we determine **which** number we Chose over the set of two?

Comment: Which rule? If your question is how to define a square root function on the complex plane, [the answer is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number) (and it has been hashed and rehashed on this site, I must add).

Comment: I have realized that the rule e^{xB}=(e^x)^B is only valid if B is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one is working in **real** analysis, the expression $x^{1/2}$ ($x>0$) is by definition $\sqrt{x}$, which is *defined* to be the positive real number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. Hence one has 
$$
1^{1/2}=1.
$$

If one is working in **complex** analysis, $1^{1/2}$ can be viewed as the *multivalued* function $f(z)=z^{1/2}$ evaluated at $z=1$. In this context, since $f$ is multivalued, it is incorrect to write $1^{1/2}=1$.

---

The identity $(e^x)^y = e^{xy}$ holds for real numbers $x$ and $y$, but assuming its truth for complex numbers leads to paradox like the one you have observed.

To quote Wikipedia:

> Some identities for powers and logarithms for positive real numbers will fail for complex numbers, no matter how complex powers and complex logarithms are defined as single-valued functions.

See [Failure of power and logarithm identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities) for more examples.